# Android Thread Process.setThreadPriority

Tags: android, multithreading, cgroups

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int newThreadCount;
private int uiCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            while (true) {
                newThreadCount++;
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    while (uiCount < 100000000) {
        uiCount++;
    }
    Log.d("TEST", "uiCount=" + uiCount + " newThreadCount=" + newThreadCount);
}
```

I know
Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)

let Thread t run in **bg_non_interactive** cgroups

1. Run the code above, Log print uiCount=100000000 and newThreadCount=50000000(around)
2. Remove Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND) then
       run the code again, Log print is almost the same.

So what is the function of Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What doesn't the documentation answer of your question?

Comment: Does Thread with Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND) or Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FORCEGROUND) effect thread occupies CPU's time?

Comment: Please post updates the further updates to your main post, don't keep them in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Android APIs already assign worker threads a background priority for you (for example, see the source code for HandlerThread and AsyncTask).

It is important to remember, however, that this will not always be the case. Threads and ExecutorServices that are instantiated on the main UI thread, for example, will inherit a default, foreground priority, making lag more likely and possibly hurting the application’s performance. In these cases, you should always remember to set the thread’s priority by calling Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND) before the Thread is run. Doing so is straightforward, as shown in the example below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

    // ...
  }
}).start();
```